# Is a “‘Junction’ Table” the same as a Weak Entity?

Tags: database-design, terminology

Is a “‘Junction’-Table” basically just the table that sits between two entities that have a many-to-many (M-M) relationship?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A junction table is a weak entity, but a [weak entity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_entity) often is not a junction table.  A junction table is not the same as a weak entity.  A junction table is a type of weak entity.

Tables used to resolve repeating groups are also weak entities.  These are only junction tables if the repeating group contains a repeated foreign key relationship.

Comment: Should this read, "...but a weak entity may *not* be..."?

Comment: @AirThomas I believe *may not* would imply *likely is* which I did not want to do.  Similarly I would state *A coin may be a quarter* rather than *A coin may not be a quarter*.

Answer (score 3):

Depends how you define a "junction table". ER terminology tends to be somewhat ambiguous when used to describe relational database concepts.

A junction table typically means or can mean any table with two or more foreign keys.

A weak entity on the other hand is represented by a table whose primary key includes at least one foreign key attribute. That doesn't have to be the case for a junction table (i.e. a table with more than one foreign key).